# In C++ how do I declare an array which will be used by a class?

Tags: arrays, string, class, declaration

The Google searches I have tried lead me to people with bugs in their programs. I'd rather just know how to do it properly than backtrack from faulty code.

I have an array, it's const int.

In my class I want to initialise a different array but with the same number of elements.

After initialising the first array, in the class I've tried:

```
int array[array.length()];
```

But the compiler moans it isn't a constant expression.

Even when I

```
const string thestring = "Dummy example";
const static int strlen = (int)thestring.length();
```

Then later in the class I:

```
class dostuff {
    int newstring[strlen];
);
```

The compiler Still complains at me.

This leaves me trying first do declare, eg:

```
const string thestring = "Dummy";
```

Then in the class, just count the elements by hand:

```
class Enigmatise {
    int duplicatelengthstring[5]; // Just counted by hand. :-(
);
```

The compiler is happy now it has a constant expression, but I'm not happy because if I change the definition of the principle string to "More characters", it's then down to me to count them out by hand, or cout them with .length(), and then use a new constant numerical expression in the class, doing it all by hand. This looks accident prone.

Therefore, if I have a

```
const string thestring = "Dummy example";
```

How do I then declare, in a class, another array of equal length to the dummy within class?

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic allocation;

```
class anotherclass {
        const std::string thestring;
        int * const otherArray;

        anotherclass() : thestring("some string"),
                         otherArray(new int[(int)thestring.length()]){}
        ~anotherclass(){delete[] otherArray;}
   };
```

---

EDIT: This compiles without warnings

```
class anotherclass {        
    static const std::string thestring;
    static const int strlen;
    public:
    void dosomething( ){int g[strlen]; }
};


const std::string anotherclass::thestring = "mystring";
const int anotherclass::strlen = anotherclass::thestring.length();
```

Comment: If you don't want/can use dynamic allocation, under C++11 it may be possible to work something out using `constexpr` but I'm not sure.

Comment: I gave it an attempt, but `std::basic_string<T>` isn't a literal type.  Due to that, we can't: make `constexpr std::string`s, use `std::basic_string<T>::operator[]` or `size()` in a `constexpr` function, or use `c_str()` in a `constexpr` function to get the underlying C string and check the length from there.  It also seems that the ol' `sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])` idiom won't work; when used with his string, it evaluates to `32` instead of `13`.  There's likely a way to do it, but I'm not skilled enough yet to figure out what it is.

Comment: It would be easy to do if he was using a C string; `string_literal`, as proposed in paper N4121, would also help, but I don't know what happened with that, if anything.  At the moment, the best thing I can think of is to make a compile-time string class, such as `literal_str` ( https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/482276/c-11-compile-time-string-concatenation-with-constexpr ), and give it a `constexpr size_t size()` function.  He'd also need to make a way to use it with `std::string`, if needed.  I honestly don't know how to use `constexpr` to get the size otherwise.